# Eigen Dynamic matrices size

Tags: eigen

Say one has the following code:

```
cout<< sizeof(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1 , 0 , 10, 10>)<<endl;
cout<< sizeof(Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>)<<endl;
```

The first line outputs 3664 bytes, and the second one, 24 bytes.

I am trying to understand why specifying the maximum size results in this?

Computer architecture is x64.

Answer (score 1):

hm, you probably did a copy-paste mistake, because, as expected, I obtain:

```
816
24
```

Indeed, as explain in the documentation of [Eigen::Matrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html), specifying the maximum sizes at compile time amounts, in your case, to the following structure:

```
struct {
  double data[10*10]; // 800 Bytes
  long rows, cols;    // 16 Bytes
};
```